# MySQL - count elements having entries in another table (inner join)

Tags: mysql, count, inner-join

Given the following schema http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbc328 I have two tables:

**names**

```
id
name
```

and

**addresses**

```
id
nameId
address
```

I need to find out how many resources in `names` have a certain number of addresses, for instance 3 addresses each.

Using the following query:

```
SELECT n.id
FROM `names` n
INNER JOIN `addresses` a on a.nameId = n.id
group by n.id
having count(a.id) = 3
```

I can find out which are those names, but I need a `count()`.

When trying to use count, such as

```
SELECT count(n.id) as cnt
FROM `names` n
INNER JOIN `addresses` a on a.nameId = n.id
group by n.id
having count(a.id) = 3
```

is not working because I'm using `group by`. I know I could achieve this by using nested queries, but I want to know whether it can be accomplished using **a single query**.

EDIT: The expected response should be a single row containing a single field 'cnt' that should return the number of names having 3 addresses each.

e.g. the response should be `2` in this case, since the only entries that match our criteria are `1` and `4`

EDIT: Here's the nested query that's working

```
select count(n.id) as cnt
from `names` n
where n.id IN (SELECT n.id
FROM `names` n
INNER JOIN `addresses` a on a.nameId = n.id
group by n.id
having count(a.id) = 3)
```

I want to achieve the same thing WITHOUT having to use a nested query

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: what your expected output as per your given table ?

Comment: The expected response should be a single row containing a single field 'cnt' that should return the number of entries in the `names` table, having 3 addresses each.

Comment: You have to use your query as a subquery and apply `count` in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
  (SELECT a.nameId
   FROM `names` n
   INNER JOIN `addresses` a ON a.nameId = n.id
   GROUP BY n.id
   HAVING count(a.id) = 3) AS TEMP
```

Comment: I require a query that returns a single row with a single 'cnt' field that contains the total number of entries in the names table, having 3 addresses each 

e.g. the response should be `2` in this case, since the only entries that match our criteria are `1` and `4`

Comment: Why do you need  to count inside?

Comment: I accidentally updated your question instead of mine :S

Comment: Could you add some explanation to this answer?